# SAP Cloud Platform Integration - Send file to external endpoint

Tags: post, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

I have a very simple flow in SAP CPI, I use a "content modifier", add "Authorization" and "Content-Type", but it doesn't work. The zip file is not sent, it even appears for download in the trace, but it does not reach the server.

Can anyone help us?

I'm using HTTP, sending file by postman.

Comment: Hi! it would be helpful if you could provide more information regarding for example the protocol you're using (http, soap ecc..), the error logs and so on..

Comment: I tried to put pictures but it didn't work. I will put it again. Thanks.

Comment: Integration Flow -> Runtime configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm6Ob.jpg
HTTPS -> Connection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH5Mo.jpg
Content Modifier -> Message Header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cziu.jpg
HTTP -> Connection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyYp.jpg

Comment: your configuration seems legit from the screenshots. could you post the trace log? you should receive an HTTP response code (eg: 400, 500 etc). And also: did you try to call the server with postman?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please try with Super User or SAP forums.

Comment: @SandraRossi: do you mean that questions regarding BTC Cloud Integration are not relevant to SO?

Comment: Yes, I understand. One of the solutions I've seen involves "groovy scripting". I posted here because there might be a solution for groovy too

Comment: i'm sending the zip with postman.

Comment: @manuel_b it depends. Any programming question concerning CPI can be asked in Stack Overflow. Sometimes, the frontier is not obvious, like Excel formulas for instance.

Comment: @manuel_b, do you know about it?

Comment: @RenatoVitor in SCPI I've already sent HTTP POST with a payload in the past but its difficult to tell what's going wrong without a trace log.

Comment: can i send to your email? if yes, send me an email so i can reply to you (renatovitor01@gmail.com) thanks.